# Cannot read property 'map' - production build for Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

maybe somebody already had this problem. Trying to run this in angular 6 project:

```
ng build --prod --aot=true
```

and it gives me this error: **ERROR in Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

I don't have idea what might be the problem, i've tried also to delete node_module + package-lock.json and do once again npm install, but it didn't help. Also tried to run ng build without --aot=true which in the end gave me the same error.

Angular CLI version is: 6.2.6

Node version: 8.11.3

Any ideas guys of how can i figure out with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you attempting to call `.map()` on an array that is null or undefined?

Comment: is the issue related particularly with prod build?

Comment: Daniel C. yes it works fine with simple ng build

Comment: @alokstar yes, with simple ng build, it works fine and application also works fine. It gives me this error just on production build

Comment: @Brandon in application everything works fine, i don't think this is related with that

Comment: It's entirely possible for the application to work correctly when using the JIT compiler and fail in a production build.

Comment: please read very carefully the aot documentation https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler, errors during aot compilation sometimes are very difficult to find, just try to review the entire exception trace (it will be fantastic if you can post the entire error) and check your html templates.